# GMT Offset to PHP timezone

Tags: php, timezone, gmt

Is it possible to have something like?

```
$offset    = -05:00; 
$timezone  = getTimeZone($offset); //return America/New_York 
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
```

How about the DST(Day Saving Light)  if yes?

**EDIT**

What i have tried is

```
function php_date_default_timezone_set($GMT,$timestamp) { 
              $timezones = array( 
                  '-12:00'=>'Pacific/Kwajalein', 
                  '-11:00'=>'Pacific/Samoa', 
                  '-10:00'=>'Pacific/Honolulu', 
                  '-09:00'=>'America/Juneau', 
                  '-08:00'=>'America/Los_Angeles', 
                  '-07:00'=>'America/Denver', 
                  '-06:00'=>'America/Mexico_City', 
                  '-05:00'=>'America/New_York', 
                  '-04:00'=>'America/Caracas', 
                  '-03:30'=>'America/St_Johns', 
                  '-03:00'=>'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires', 
                  '-02:00'=>'Atlantic/Azores',
                  '-01:00'=>'Atlantic/Azores', 
                  '+00:00'=>'Europe/London', 
                  '+01:00'=>'Europe/Paris', 
                  '+02:00'=>'Europe/Helsinki', 
                  '+03:00'=>'Europe/Moscow', 
                  '+03:30'=>'Asia/Tehran', 
                  '+04:00'=>'Asia/Baku', 
                  '+04:30'=>'Asia/Kabul', 
                  '+05:00'=>'Asia/Karachi', 
                  '+05:30'=>'Asia/Calcutta', 
                  '+06:00'=>'Asia/Colombo', 
                  '+07:00'=>'Asia/Bangkok', 
                  '+08:00'=>'Asia/Singapore', 
                  '+09:00'=>'Asia/Tokyo', 
                  '+09:00'=>'Australia/Darwin', 
                  '+10:00'=>'Pacific/Guam', 
                  '+11:00'=>'Asia/Magadan', 
                  '+12:00'=>'Asia/Kamchatka' 
              ); 

    date_default_timezone_set($timezones[$GMT]);

    return  date_default_timezone_get();
}  

    echo php_date_default_timezone_set('-05:00',time()); 
   // returns America/New_York
```

But i don't know whether this way is correct or not?

Comment: DST changes randomly as governments change their minds. You can't hard-code yourself a reliable list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because there's no such reverse correlation. There are many timezones which currently have a `-05:00` offset. That's why you should use timezone identifiers to identify timezones, not offsets.

Comment: Please check the function what i have tried and please let me know whether this way is correct or not?

Comment: Well, it's *a* way, but as I said, there are many timezones with the same offset at any given time. The function will give you *a* matching timezone, but whether this is the *correct* answer or not depends on what you deem a correct answer.

Comment: I concur with deceze. There is no correct way to do this, only hacky ways. You simply cannot determine what timezone anything is, based on an offset. At most you could compile a big list of potential candidates.

Comment: Agreed with `deceze` and `Evert`, what i want is i am storing the user selected timezone in db as `+00:00` format, based on the user selected timezone we need to display the content. Could you please let me know the way to this?

Comment: @LearneR You are screwed, as simple as that. :P Storing the offset is the wrong thing to do, since the offset changes throughout the year based on DST rules.

Comment: Yes, the offset is NOT enough to make a decision of timezone. But there is a JavaScript library that can help you determine the timezone (but not the offset). Once you have the timezone you can use that to do datetime normalizations on the server side. Here: https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me from bringing back an old question, but i was having the same issue using the Offset, but instead, decided to use this list. (From Google Calendar)

Instead of storing the offset, store the actual name "America/Phoenix"

This is what I have now for when users select a time zone. Its perfect lineup of the major timezones, and PHP ready. http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

[image: timezones]

```
<select name="timezones">
<option value="Pacific/Midway">(GMT-11:00) Midway</option>
<option value="Pacific/Niue">(GMT-11:00) Niue</option>
<option value="Pacific/Pago_Pago">(GMT-11:00) Pago Pago</option>
<option value="Pacific/Honolulu">(GMT-10:00) Hawaii Time</option>
<option value="Pacific/Rarotonga">(GMT-10:00) Rarotonga</option>
<option value="Pacific/Tahiti">(GMT-10:00) Tahiti</option>
<option value="Pacific/Marquesas">(GMT-09:30) Marquesas</option>
<option value="America/Anchorage">(GMT-09:00) Alaska Time</option>
<option value="Pacific/Gambier">(GMT-09:00) Gambier</option>
<option value="America/Los_Angeles">(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time</option>
<option value="America/Tijuana">(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time - Tijuana</option>
<option value="America/Vancouver">(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time - Vancouver</option>
<option value="America/Whitehorse">(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time - Whitehorse</option>
<option value="Pacific/Pitcairn">(GMT-08:00) Pitcairn</option>
<option value="America/Dawson_Creek">(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time - Dawson Creek</option>
<option value="America/Denver">(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time</option>
<option value="America/Edmonton">(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time - Edmonton</option>
<option value="America/Hermosillo">(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time - Hermosillo</option>
<option value="America/Mazatlan">(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time - Chihuahua, Mazatlan</option>
<option value="America/Phoenix">(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time - Arizona</option>
<option value="America/Yellowknife">(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time - Yellowknife</option>
<option value="America/Belize">(GMT-06:00) Belize</option>
<option value="America/Chicago">(GMT-06:00) Central Time</option>
<option value="America/Costa_Rica">(GMT-06:00) Costa Rica</option>
<option value="America/El_Salvador">(GMT-06:00) El Salvador</option>
<option value="America/Guatemala">(GMT-06:00) Guatemala</option>
<option value="America/Managua">(GMT-06:00) Managua</option>
<option value="America/Mexico_City">(GMT-06:00) Central Time - Mexico City</option>
<option value="America/Regina">(GMT-06:00) Central Time - Regina</option>
<option value="America/Tegucigalpa">(GMT-06:00) Central Time - Tegucigalpa</option>
<option value="America/Winnipeg">(GMT-06:00) Central Time - Winnipeg</option>
<option value="Pacific/Easter">(GMT-06:00) Easter Island</option>
<option value="Pacific/Galapagos">(GMT-06:00) Galapagos</option>
<option value="America/Bogota">(GMT-05:00) Bogota</option>
<option value="America/Cayman">(GMT-05:00) Cayman</option>
<option value="America/Guayaquil">(GMT-05:00) Guayaquil</option>
<option value="America/Havana">(GMT-05:00) Havana</option>
<option value="America/Iqaluit">(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time - Iqaluit</option>
<option value="America/Jamaica">(GMT-05:00) Jamaica</option>
<option value="America/Lima">(GMT-05:00) Lima</option>
<option value="America/Montreal">(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time - Montreal</option>
<option value="America/Nassau">(GMT-05:00) Nassau</option>
<option value="America/New_York">(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time</option>
<option value="America/Panama">(GMT-05:00) Panama</option>
<option value="America/Port-au-Prince">(GMT-05:00) Port-au-Prince</option>
<option value="America/Rio_Branco">(GMT-05:00) Rio Branco</option>
<option value="America/Toronto">(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time - Toronto</option>
<option value="America/Caracas">(GMT-04:30) Caracas</option>
<option value="America/Antigua">(GMT-04:00) Antigua</option>
<option value="America/Asuncion">(GMT-04:00) Asuncion</option>
<option value="America/Barbados">(GMT-04:00) Barbados</option>
<option value="America/Boa_Vista">(GMT-04:00) Boa Vista</option>
<option value="America/Campo_Grande">(GMT-04:00) Campo Grande</option>
<option value="America/Cuiaba">(GMT-04:00) Cuiaba</option>
<option value="America/Curacao">(GMT-04:00) Curacao</option>
<option value="America/Grand_Turk">(GMT-04:00) Grand Turk</option>
<option value="America/Guyana">(GMT-04:00) Guyana</option>
<option value="America/Halifax">(GMT-04:00) Atlantic Time - Halifax</option>
<option value="America/La_Paz">(GMT-04:00) La Paz</option>
<option value="America/Manaus">(GMT-04:00) Manaus</option>
<option value="America/Martinique">(GMT-04:00) Martinique</option>
<option value="America/Port_of_Spain">(GMT-04:00) Port of Spain</option>
<option value="America/Porto_Velho">(GMT-04:00) Porto Velho</option>
<option value="America/Puerto_Rico">(GMT-04:00) Puerto Rico</option>
<option value="America/Santiago">(GMT-04:00) Santiago</option>
<option value="America/Santo_Domingo">(GMT-04:00) Santo Domingo</option>
<option value="America/Thule">(GMT-04:00) Thule</option>
<option value="Antarctica/Palmer">(GMT-04:00) Palmer</option>
<option value="Atlantic/Bermuda">(GMT-04:00) Bermuda</option>
<option value="America/St_Johns">(GMT-03:30) Newfoundland Time - St. Johns</option>
<option value="America/Araguaina">(GMT-03:00) Araguaina</option>
<option value="America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires">(GMT-03:00) Buenos Aires</option>
<option value="America/Bahia">(GMT-03:00) Salvador</option>
<option value="America/Belem">(GMT-03:00) Belem</option>
<option value="America/Cayenne">(GMT-03:00) Cayenne</option>
<option value="America/Fortaleza">(GMT-03:00) Fortaleza</option>
<option value="America/Godthab">(GMT-03:00) Godthab</option>
<option value="America/Maceio">(GMT-03:00) Maceio</option>
<option value="America/Miquelon">(GMT-03:00) Miquelon</option>
<option value="America/Montevideo">(GMT-03:00) Montevideo</option>
<option value="America/Paramaribo">(GMT-03:00) Paramaribo</option>
<option value="America/Recife">(GMT-03:00) Recife</option>
<option value="America/Sao_Paulo">(GMT-03:00) Sao Paulo</option>
<option value="Antarctica/Rothera">(GMT-03:00) Rothera</option>
<option value="Atlantic/Stanley">(GMT-03:00) Stanley</option>
<option value="America/Noronha">(GMT-02:00) Noronha</option>
<option value="Atlantic/South_Georgia">(GMT-02:00) South Georgia</option>
<option value="America/Scoresbysund">(GMT-01:00) Scoresbysund</option>
<option value="Atlantic/Azores">(GMT-01:00) Azores</option>
<option value="Atlantic/Cape_Verde">(GMT-01:00) Cape Verde</option>
<option value="Africa/Abidjan">(GMT+00:00) Abidjan</option>
<option value="Africa/Accra">(GMT+00:00) Accra</option>
<option value="Africa/Bissau">(GMT+00:00) Bissau</option>
<option value="Africa/Casablanca">(GMT+00:00) Casablanca</option>
<option value="Africa/El_Aaiun">(GMT+00:00) El Aaiun</option>
<option value="Africa/Monrovia">(GMT+00:00) Monrovia</option>
<option value="America/Danmarkshavn">(GMT+00:00) Danmarkshavn</option>
<option value="Atlantic/Canary">(GMT+00:00) Canary Islands</option>
<option value="Atlantic/Faroe">(GMT+00:00) Faeroe</option>
<option value="Atlantic/Reykjavik">(GMT+00:00) Reykjavik</option>
<option value="Etc/GMT">(GMT+00:00) GMT (no daylight saving)</option>
<option value="Europe/Dublin">(GMT+00:00) Dublin</option>
<option value="Europe/Lisbon">(GMT+00:00) Lisbon</option>
<option value="Europe/London">(GMT+00:00) London</option>
<option value="Africa/Algiers">(GMT+01:00) Algiers</option>
<option value="Africa/Ceuta">(GMT+01:00) Ceuta</option>
<option value="Africa/Lagos">(GMT+01:00) Lagos</option>
<option value="Africa/Ndjamena">(GMT+01:00) Ndjamena</option>
<option value="Africa/Tunis">(GMT+01:00) Tunis</option>
<option value="Africa/Windhoek">(GMT+01:00) Windhoek</option>
<option value="Europe/Amsterdam">(GMT+01:00) Amsterdam</option>
<option value="Europe/Andorra">(GMT+01:00) Andorra</option>
<option value="Europe/Belgrade">(GMT+01:00) Central European Time - Belgrade</option>
<option value="Europe/Berlin">(GMT+01:00) Berlin</option>
<option value="Europe/Brussels">(GMT+01:00) Brussels</option>
<option value="Europe/Budapest">(GMT+01:00) Budapest</option>
<option value="Europe/Copenhagen">(GMT+01:00) Copenhagen</option>
<option value="Europe/Gibraltar">(GMT+01:00) Gibraltar</option>
<option value="Europe/Luxembourg">(GMT+01:00) Luxembourg</option>
<option value="Europe/Madrid">(GMT+01:00) Madrid</option>
<option value="Europe/Malta">(GMT+01:00) Malta</option>
<option value="Europe/Monaco">(GMT+01:00) Monaco</option>
<option value="Europe/Oslo">(GMT+01:00) Oslo</option>
<option value="Europe/Paris">(GMT+01:00) Paris</option>
<option value="Europe/Prague">(GMT+01:00) Central European Time - Prague</option>
<option value="Europe/Rome">(GMT+01:00) Rome</option>
<option value="Europe/Stockholm">(GMT+01:00) Stockholm</option>
<option value="Europe/Tirane">(GMT+01:00) Tirane</option>
<option value="Europe/Vienna">(GMT+01:00) Vienna</option>
<option value="Europe/Warsaw">(GMT+01:00) Warsaw</option>
<option value="Europe/Zurich">(GMT+01:00) Zurich</option>
<option value="Africa/Cairo">(GMT+02:00) Cairo</option>
<option value="Africa/Johannesburg">(GMT+02:00) Johannesburg</option>
<option value="Africa/Maputo">(GMT+02:00) Maputo</option>
<option value="Africa/Tripoli">(GMT+02:00) Tripoli</option>
<option value="Asia/Amman">(GMT+02:00) Amman</option>
<option value="Asia/Beirut">(GMT+02:00) Beirut</option>
<option value="Asia/Damascus">(GMT+02:00) Damascus</option>
<option value="Asia/Gaza">(GMT+02:00) Gaza</option>
<option value="Asia/Jerusalem">(GMT+02:00) Jerusalem</option>
<option value="Asia/Nicosia">(GMT+02:00) Nicosia</option>
<option value="Europe/Athens">(GMT+02:00) Athens</option>
<option value="Europe/Bucharest">(GMT+02:00) Bucharest</option>
<option value="Europe/Chisinau">(GMT+02:00) Chisinau</option>
<option value="Europe/Helsinki">(GMT+02:00) Helsinki</option>
<option value="Europe/Istanbul">(GMT+02:00) Istanbul</option>
<option value="Europe/Kaliningrad">(GMT+02:00) Moscow-01 - Kaliningrad</option>
<option value="Europe/Kiev">(GMT+02:00) Kiev</option>
<option value="Europe/Riga">(GMT+02:00) Riga</option>
<option value="Europe/Sofia">(GMT+02:00) Sofia</option>
<option value="Europe/Tallinn">(GMT+02:00) Tallinn</option>
<option value="Europe/Vilnius">(GMT+02:00) Vilnius</option>
<option value="Africa/Addis_Ababa">(GMT+03:00) Addis Ababa</option>
<option value="Africa/Asmara">(GMT+03:00) Asmera</option>
<option value="Africa/Dar_es_Salaam">(GMT+03:00) Dar es Salaam</option>
<option value="Africa/Djibouti">(GMT+03:00) Djibouti</option>
<option value="Africa/Kampala">(GMT+03:00) Kampala</option>
<option value="Africa/Khartoum">(GMT+03:00) Khartoum</option>
<option value="Africa/Mogadishu">(GMT+03:00) Mogadishu</option>
<option value="Africa/Nairobi">(GMT+03:00) Nairobi</option>
<option value="Antarctica/Syowa">(GMT+03:00) Syowa</option>
<option value="Asia/Aden">(GMT+03:00) Aden</option>
<option value="Asia/Baghdad">(GMT+03:00) Baghdad</option>
<option value="Asia/Bahrain">(GMT+03:00) Bahrain</option>
<option value="Asia/Kuwait">(GMT+03:00) Kuwait</option>
<option value="Asia/Qatar">(GMT+03:00) Qatar</option>
<option value="Asia/Riyadh">(GMT+03:00) Riyadh</option>
<option value="Europe/Minsk">(GMT+03:00) Minsk</option>
<option value="Europe/Moscow">(GMT+03:00) Moscow+00</option>
<option value="Indian/Antananarivo">(GMT+03:00) Antananarivo</option>
<option value="Indian/Comoro">(GMT+03:00) Comoro</option>
<option value="Indian/Mayotte">(GMT+03:00) Mayotte</option>
<option value="Asia/Tehran">(GMT+03:30) Tehran</option>
<option value="Asia/Baku">(GMT+04:00) Baku</option>
<option value="Asia/Dubai">(GMT+04:00) Dubai</option>
<option value="Asia/Muscat">(GMT+04:00) Muscat</option>
<option value="Asia/Tbilisi">(GMT+04:00) Tbilisi</option>
<option value="Asia/Yerevan">(GMT+04:00) Yerevan</option>
<option value="Europe/Samara">(GMT+04:00) Moscow+00 - Samara</option>
<option value="Indian/Mahe">(GMT+04:00) Mahe</option>
<option value="Indian/Mauritius">(GMT+04:00) Mauritius</option>
<option value="Indian/Reunion">(GMT+04:00) Reunion</option>
<option value="Asia/Kabul">(GMT+04:30) Kabul</option>
<option value="Antarctica/Mawson">(GMT+05:00) Mawson</option>
<option value="Asia/Aqtau">(GMT+05:00) Aqtau</option>
<option value="Asia/Aqtobe">(GMT+05:00) Aqtobe</option>
<option value="Asia/Ashgabat">(GMT+05:00) Ashgabat</option>
<option value="Asia/Dushanbe">(GMT+05:00) Dushanbe</option>
<option value="Asia/Karachi">(GMT+05:00) Karachi</option>
<option value="Asia/Tashkent">(GMT+05:00) Tashkent</option>
<option value="Asia/Yekaterinburg">(GMT+05:00) Moscow+02 - Yekaterinburg</option>
<option value="Indian/Kerguelen">(GMT+05:00) Kerguelen</option>
<option value="Indian/Maldives">(GMT+05:00) Maldives</option>
<option value="Asia/Calcutta">(GMT+05:30) India Standard Time</option>
<option value="Asia/Colombo">(GMT+05:30) Colombo</option>
<option value="Asia/Katmandu">(GMT+05:45) Katmandu</option>
<option value="Antarctica/Vostok">(GMT+06:00) Vostok</option>
<option value="Asia/Almaty">(GMT+06:00) Almaty</option>
<option value="Asia/Bishkek">(GMT+06:00) Bishkek</option>
<option value="Asia/Dhaka">(GMT+06:00) Dhaka</option>
<option value="Asia/Omsk">(GMT+06:00) Moscow+03 - Omsk, Novosibirsk</option>
<option value="Asia/Thimphu">(GMT+06:00) Thimphu</option>
<option value="Indian/Chagos">(GMT+06:00) Chagos</option>
<option value="Asia/Rangoon">(GMT+06:30) Rangoon</option>
<option value="Indian/Cocos">(GMT+06:30) Cocos</option>
<option value="Antarctica/Davis">(GMT+07:00) Davis</option>
<option value="Asia/Bangkok">(GMT+07:00) Bangkok</option>
<option value="Asia/Hovd">(GMT+07:00) Hovd</option>
<option value="Asia/Jakarta">(GMT+07:00) Jakarta</option>
<option value="Asia/Krasnoyarsk">(GMT+07:00) Moscow+04 - Krasnoyarsk</option>
<option value="Asia/Saigon">(GMT+07:00) Hanoi</option>
<option value="Indian/Christmas">(GMT+07:00) Christmas</option>
<option value="Antarctica/Casey">(GMT+08:00) Casey</option>
<option value="Asia/Brunei">(GMT+08:00) Brunei</option>
<option value="Asia/Choibalsan">(GMT+08:00) Choibalsan</option>
<option value="Asia/Hong_Kong">(GMT+08:00) Hong Kong</option>
<option value="Asia/Irkutsk">(GMT+08:00) Moscow+05 - Irkutsk</option>
<option value="Asia/Kuala_Lumpur">(GMT+08:00) Kuala Lumpur</option>
<option value="Asia/Macau">(GMT+08:00) Macau</option>
<option value="Asia/Makassar">(GMT+08:00) Makassar</option>
<option value="Asia/Manila">(GMT+08:00) Manila</option>
<option value="Asia/Shanghai">(GMT+08:00) China Time - Beijing</option>
<option value="Asia/Singapore">(GMT+08:00) Singapore</option>
<option value="Asia/Taipei">(GMT+08:00) Taipei</option>
<option value="Asia/Ulaanbaatar">(GMT+08:00) Ulaanbaatar</option>
<option value="Australia/Perth">(GMT+08:00) Western Time - Perth</option>
<option value="Asia/Dili">(GMT+09:00) Dili</option>
<option value="Asia/Jayapura">(GMT+09:00) Jayapura</option>
<option value="Asia/Pyongyang">(GMT+09:00) Pyongyang</option>
<option value="Asia/Seoul">(GMT+09:00) Seoul</option>
<option value="Asia/Tokyo">(GMT+09:00) Tokyo</option>
<option value="Asia/Yakutsk">(GMT+09:00) Moscow+06 - Yakutsk</option>
<option value="Pacific/Palau">(GMT+09:00) Palau</option>
<option value="Australia/Adelaide">(GMT+09:30) Central Time - Adelaide</option>
<option value="Australia/Darwin">(GMT+09:30) Central Time - Darwin</option>
<option value="Antarctica/DumontDUrville">(GMT+10:00) Dumont D'Urville</option>
<option value="Asia/Magadan">(GMT+10:00) Moscow+08 - Magadan</option>
<option value="Asia/Vladivostok">(GMT+10:00) Moscow+07 - Yuzhno-Sakhalinsk</option>
<option value="Australia/Brisbane">(GMT+10:00) Eastern Time - Brisbane</option>
<option value="Australia/Hobart">(GMT+10:00) Eastern Time - Hobart</option>
<option value="Australia/Sydney">(GMT+10:00) Eastern Time - Melbourne, Sydney</option>
<option value="Pacific/Chuuk">(GMT+10:00) Truk</option>
<option value="Pacific/Guam">(GMT+10:00) Guam</option>
<option value="Pacific/Port_Moresby">(GMT+10:00) Port Moresby</option>
<option value="Pacific/Saipan">(GMT+10:00) Saipan</option>
<option value="Pacific/Efate">(GMT+11:00) Efate</option>
<option value="Pacific/Guadalcanal">(GMT+11:00) Guadalcanal</option>
<option value="Pacific/Kosrae">(GMT+11:00) Kosrae</option>
<option value="Pacific/Noumea">(GMT+11:00) Noumea</option>
<option value="Pacific/Pohnpei">(GMT+11:00) Ponape</option>
<option value="Pacific/Norfolk">(GMT+11:30) Norfolk</option>
<option value="Asia/Kamchatka">(GMT+12:00) Moscow+08 - Petropavlovsk-Kamchatskiy</option>
<option value="Pacific/Auckland">(GMT+12:00) Auckland</option>
<option value="Pacific/Fiji">(GMT+12:00) Fiji</option>
<option value="Pacific/Funafuti">(GMT+12:00) Funafuti</option>
<option value="Pacific/Kwajalein">(GMT+12:00) Kwajalein</option>
<option value="Pacific/Majuro">(GMT+12:00) Majuro</option>
<option value="Pacific/Nauru">(GMT+12:00) Nauru</option>
<option value="Pacific/Tarawa">(GMT+12:00) Tarawa</option>
<option value="Pacific/Wake">(GMT+12:00) Wake</option>
<option value="Pacific/Wallis">(GMT+12:00) Wallis</option>
<option value="Pacific/Apia">(GMT+13:00) Apia</option>
<option value="Pacific/Enderbury">(GMT+13:00) Enderbury</option>
<option value="Pacific/Fakaofo">(GMT+13:00) Fakaofo</option>
<option value="Pacific/Tongatapu">(GMT+13:00) Tongatapu</option>
<option value="Pacific/Kiritimati">(GMT+14:00) Kiritimati</option>
```

Now in PHP you can use the value you stored from the select box, and input directly into the timezone set.

```
date_default_timezone_set($time_zone_name);
```

The user would now select a timezone they know locally. I know it can be a lot, but there are ways to do it without the offset.